# Qt C++ Get data from every cell of a selected row from a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any way to get data from a selected row from a table view? i've used 
`QModelIndexList ids = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();` which returns a list of the indexes of the selected rows. I don't need the index. I need the data from every cell of the selected row.

Comment: Using `QModelIndex::data(int role)` makes sence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
```

is being used for returning data. If you need to get data you are doing it here based on `QModelIndex` row and column and retrieving it from some container, maybe

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyData> > data;
```

You have to define such mapping and use it in `data()` and `setData()` functions to handle interaction with underlying model data.

Alternatively `QAbstractItemModel` and `QTreeView` offers the way to assign your class i.e. `TreeItem` to each `QModelIndex`, so you can next retrieve a pointer to each data using `static_cast` of pointer returned from **QModelIndex.internalPointer()** function:

```
TreeItem *item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
```

so then you can create some mapping:

```
// sets the role data for the item at <index> to <value> and updates 
// affected TreeItems and ModuleInfo. returns true if successful
// otherwise returns false
bool ModuleEnablerDialogTreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex & index,
    const QVariant & value, int role) {
  if (role
      == Qt::CheckStateRole&& index.column()==ModuleEnablerDialog_CheckBoxColumn) {
    TreeItem *item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    Qt::CheckState checkedState;
    if (value == Qt::Checked) {
      checkedState = Qt::Checked;
    } else if (value == Qt::Unchecked) {
      checkedState = Qt::Unchecked;
    } else {
      checkedState = Qt::PartiallyChecked;
    }
    //set this item currentlyEnabled and check state
    if (item->hierarchy() == 1) { // the last level in the tree hierarchy
      item->mModuleInfo.currentlyEnabled = (
          checkedState == Qt::Checked ? true : false);
      item->setData(ModuleEnablerDialog_CheckBoxColumn, checkedState);
      if (mRoot_Systems != NULL) {
        updateModelItems(item);
      }
    } else { // every level other than last level
      if (checkedState == Qt::Checked || checkedState == Qt::Unchecked) {
        item->setData(index.column(), checkedState);
        // update children
        item->updateChildren(checkedState);
        // and parents
        updateParents(item);
```

[example of implementation](https://github.com/cf16/examples/blob/master/qt/ModuleEnablerDialogTreeModel.cpp)

Answer (score 9):

you can Try this

```
int rowidx = ui->tblView->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row();
ui->txt1->setText(model->index(rowidx , 0).data().toString());
ui->txt2->setText(model->index(rowidx , 1).data().toString());
ui->txt3->setText(model->index(rowidx , 2).data().toString());
ui->txt4->setText(model->index(rowidx , 3).data().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this for getting data. selectedRows(0) indicates first column of selected rows, selectedRows(1) indicates second column of selected rows row likewise

QItemSelectionModel *select = ui->existingtable->selectionModel();
qDebug()<<select->selectedRows(0).value(0).data().toString();
qDebug()<<select->selectedRows(1).value(0).data().toString();
qDebug()<<select->selectedRows(2).value(0).data().toString();
qDebug()<<select->selectedRows(3).value(0).data().toString();
```